# Database design: conjunction

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table which represents Users:`id, name`. **The table is huge, about 100 million rows.** 
Also users have some property, lets say City of birth. This is optional field so only a small part of users (**let's say only 5%**) have provided it. So I also have a table with cities: `id, name`. Relation is 1 to many - user can have only one city, and the a city can be a bithplace for many users.

The question is: how to connect them?

a) Adding a column `city_id` to the users table. (doomed for 95 millions nulls for users who don't have the property)

b) Creating a third, conjunction table `user_city: user_id,city_id` (With purpose to omit that huge number of NULLs if a).

Also, please, keep in mind that the application needs to

```
select user.name ... where city_id=xxx
```

So the `city_id` column needs to be indexed in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because any non-alien user has only one birth city (unless he was born in a taxi), it seems silly and wasteful to have a table of birth city indexed by User ID. I would put birth city right in the user table where (as I claim) it belongs, notwithstanding that most city fields will be NULL.

But, forgetting my mere opinion, this is the classic time vs. space problem, the space consideration being the millions of extraneous, useless NULLs; and the extra time being the millions of extraneous, useless SELECTs into the city table.

What does your solution to that problem tell you?

Comment: I consider this option because it seems wasteful to me to have all that NULLs in the index on city_id column (in case when only 10 of 100 000 000 users have provided their birth city). RAM is limited so I want to minimize indexs' size as much as possible.

Comment: There's your answer: in your case, space is more valuable than time.